# Send Google Analytics data to custom Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-analytics

I have added in my website this [library](http://www.chartjs.org) in order to display charts. Everything is working good when I send to the charts custom data however, I was wondering How I could implement the chart.js library to show Google Analytics. I already have google analytics working using google charts, is there a way to send the data to custom chart?

Working google chart

```
var chart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:date',
      'metrics': 'ga:users',
      <?php echo $start_date_script ?>
      <?php echo $end_date_script ?>
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'PIE',
      container: 'timeline',
      options: {
        width: '100%',
        region: 'world', // Western Europe
        displayMode: 'regions',
        magnifyingGlass: {enable: true, zoomFactor: 7.5}
      }
    }
  });
```

Custom chart.js to fetch google analytics

```
// Line chart

      var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
        datasets : [
        {
          label: "My First dataset",
          fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
          strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
          pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          data : ['ga:users','ga:users','ga:users', 'ga:users','ga:users','ga:users','ga:users','ga:users','ga:users','ga:users','ga:users','ga:users']
        }
        ]

      } // lineChartData
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/

Comment: You need to pull data with the Core Reporting API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/)